# Setfacl set permissions for future files and directories recursively

Tags: linux, permissions, setfacl

I have a directory a directory with permissions as below:

```
drwxrwxr-x   5 myuser mygroup 4.0K Mar 12 19:54 log
```

I have an application which regularly creates directories inside the folder and writes log files into those directories. Id want those directories and files to have the exact same permissions as the directory above i.e. `drwxrwxr-x`

A bit of googling and SO took me to setfacl and it looked like thats all I needed. So I went ahead and used this command to set the acl:

`setfacl -Rm g:mygroup:rwX,d:g:mygroup:rwX log/`

However I dont see the files having the same permissions as the `log/` directory and instead look like this - `drwx--x---+`. What am I missing here to make sure all the files and directories have `drwxrwxr-x` permissions